# How to improve array_rand() function with PHP?

Tags: php, random

I use the `array_rand` PHP function with an array. I use it with a data fixture function which loads a set of data in a loop like this:

```
$random_values = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    $random_values[] = array_rand(["1","2","3","4","5"]);
}
```

My result is quite always "1" in the $random_values array, the native
PHP function seems not really random, Is there another stuff to do to
improve the randomization of my algorithm?

Notice I already know there is an official documentation here, http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-rand.php.

Comment: See if seeding the rng helps with your tests: `srand ((float) microtime() * 10000000);` ... is a basic example (put that before you do the array).

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? If you're on a version of PHP old enough to require `srand()` you have much, *much* larger problems.

Comment: have a look here: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/131488/21982

Comment: There's also the fact that "random" doesn't mean "fair" or "even", particularly for small numbers of events, eg: 20. A *perfect* RNG could spit out nothing but the number 42 from now until the sun burns out because that's equally as possible as any other set of outputs.

Comment: [It seems pretty uniformly distributed](https://3v4l.org/WUJeD)

Comment: As @ishegg mentionned, it seems to be working fine, also, wouldn't it be simpler to generate a random it between 1 and 5 straight up instead of picking a random value from a predefined set?

Comment: @Sammitch I work with PHP7 thx for your answer, I tried to add a shuffle function to mix the array in the loop, it seem's to improve the dataset.

Comment: @ishegg I have made more test and add a shuffle function, it seems better.

Comment: @Sunitrams' how many times did you try this that you think `1` is almost always the result? Keep in mind what @Sammitch said: imagine you roll a die two times and you get 4 both times. Would you say the die is not fair?

Comment: Only use blockquotes for actual quotes and use bold sparingly for emphasis, not to attract attention, so please remove it.

Answer (score 0):

How's it going? So, with array_rand, it actually returns a random key within an array. Your current code does not put the random key value into the array you want to randomize. ie echo $random_value[$random_key]... See example below, hope this helps

```html
$random_values = array("1","2","3","4","5");
 
 for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
  $key = array_rand($random_values); 
  echo $random_values[$key] . "\n";
 }
```